# Emit value of the observable depends on others observables

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable

I have two subjects.

```
const a$ = new Subject<number>();
const b$ = new Subject<string>();
```

I want to have third observable, that is based on the two subjects above. So depends of the emited subject and its value i want to make computation and emit some value.

I tried:

```
const result$ = a$.pipe(merge(b$))
```

But if i add `map` after `merge` i can't detect from what observable is value from. Also `combineLatest` is not a case, because i want to get result even if one of the subjects is not emitted.

Comment: Look into `combineLatest` or `withLatestFrom` or `zip` (depending on your use case) in conjunction with `startWith`. If you do some computation on both streams you should have 'default' value if no proper value is present

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To distinguish what comes from where, you can map incoming values:

```
import {merge} from 'rxjs';

const result$ = merge(
  a$.pipe(map(v => ({a: v})),
  b$.pipe(map(v => ({b: v}))
)
```

*As you noticed I use a static `merge` operator here. Looks more readable in this case*

Comment: Thanks. My mistake was that I tried to use `merge` from `rxjs/operators` (insted of `rxjs`) as static and can't figure out what it return. Thank you

Comment: Your welcome. You can use instance operator to get the same output too, but it looks not very readable - `a.pipe(map(a => ({a})), merge(b.pipe(map(b => ({b})))`